# Matrix Differential Equation $P'(t)= A(t)P(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

> Given $n\times n$ matrix $P(t)$ and $A(t)$ , if $P(t)$ satisfies the matrix differential equation $P'(t)= A(t)P(t)$ and the initial condition $P(0)=P_0$. Then Prove 
>   $$\det P(t) = \det P_0 \times \exp\left(\int_0^t tr(A)(s)\,ds\right)$$

If the matrix $A$ is constant matrix then it is easy.
But I don't know how to prove it when $A = A(t)$ which has dependent on variable $t$.
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Liouville's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula). (See also the proof in the linked article.)

Comment: Thanks...I didn't know it.